# sequelize association key is uppercased in response

Tags: sequelize.js

How can I make `Music` to be `music?

```
{
  id: 4
  name: "playlist 1"
  created_at: "2015-04-21T21:43:07.000Z"
  updated_at: "2015-04-23T20:44:50.000Z"
  Music: [
    {
      id: 12
      name: "Deorro - Five Hours (Static Video) [LE7ELS]"
      video_id: "K_yBUfMGvzc"
      thumbnail: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K_yBUfMGvzc/default.jpg"
      created_at: "2015-04-22T21:46:21.000Z"
      updated_at: "2015-04-22T21:46:21.000Z"
      playlist_id: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

My query looks something like:

```
.get(function (req, res) {
    db.Playlist.findAll({
      include: [db.Music]
    }).then(function (playlists) {
      if(!playlists) {
        res.status(404).json({message: 'No playlist found!'});
        return;
      }

      res.json(playlists)
    })
  })
```

Playlist model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType) {
  var Playlist = sequelize.define('Playlist', {
    name: DataType.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Playlist.hasMany(models.Music, { foreignKey: 'playlist_id' });
      }
    },
    tableName:   'playlists',
    underscored: true
  });

  return Playlist;
};
```

Music model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType) {
  var Music = sequelize.define('Music', {
    name: DataType.STRING,
    video_id:  DataType.STRING,
    thumbnail:  DataType.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Music.belongsTo(models.Playlist);
      }
    },
    tableName:   'musics',
    underscored: true
  });

  return Music;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either change the casing in your model name:

```
sequelize.define('music', ...)
```

Or provide an `as` key in the association:

```
Playlist.hasMany(Music, { as: 'music' })
```

Comment: Yep I've tried those, for the first one I get: 
 `Error: Playlist.hasMany called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model`

For the alias I get:  
`Possibly unhandled Error: Music is not associated to Playlist!`   

Note: I included my model structure in my question so you can take a look, maybe i messed up something.

Comment: 1st error: you probably need to use `models.music` in your assocation - the model is stored under its name, so you need to use the lower case version. 2nd: add `as: 'music'` to the include as well. Or save the return value from the `hasMany` call and used that instead

Answer (score 2):

**The working code for easier reference:**

Playlist model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType) {
  var Playlist = sequelize.define('Playlist', {
    name: DataType.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Playlist.hasMany(models.Music, { as: 'music', foreignKey: 'playlist_id' });
      }
    },
    tableName:   'playlists',
    underscored: true
  });

  return Playlist;
};
```

Music model: unchanged

Query:

```
controller.route('/playlist')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    db.Playlist.findAll({
      include: [{ model: db.Music, as: 'music' }]
    }).then(function (playlists) {
      if(!playlists) {
        res.status(404).json({message: 'No playlist found!'});
        return;
      }

      res.json(playlists)
    })
  })
```